# Adding custom vars with a block

Tags: blocks

I want to use the title of the block as a hyperlink (or maybe adding an image) and I do not know how can I do this.

I've been looking to [block.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/11813). I know I can modify the template the way I want.

Maybe the way to do it is defining custom variables, such as `$block->mycustom`.

If the variable is defined there is a link, if not, nothing. The problem with this approach is that I don't know where this variable should be defined.

Is that correct, or am I totally mistaken?

I am interested in an answer for Drupal 7.

Comment: How is the block created and how would you get the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a theme preprocess function for blocks to add some logic pushing variables into your block template. You can then check against those variables to output the title as a link etc.

```
THEMENAME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
 //logic here to add variables
}
```